# Implementing FTP protocol according to RFC 959

Tags: ftp, protocols, rfc

First this isn't an assignment or for employment. I want to be a better/more secure programmer.

I have read RFC [959](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt), I am at a loss as to how you actually use this to make a program that is compliant. Do I just send  the commands as strings and make the server interpret them as the command?

For instance if I sent `PWD` from the client to the server would I just make the server parse this and send back the current dir name?

Answer (score 2):

> For instance if I sent PWD from the client to the server would I just make the server parse this and send back the current dir name?

Yes. That's correct.

The FTP protocol is text-based.

An exchange between the client and the server looks literally like this:

```
Server: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.5rc3 Server (Debian)
Client: USER user
Server: 331 Password required for user
Client: PASS password
Server: 230 User user logged in
Client: SYST
Server: 215 UNIX Type: L8
Client: PWD
Server: 257 "/home/user" is the current directory
```